# Is it possible to have the new window opened in selenium, focus as the primary window on your screen?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to selenium.

I have tried many answers on stack overflow including:

[Get focus on the new window in Selenium Webdriver and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379560/get-focus-on-the-new-window-in-selenium-webdriver-and-python)

and

[Make sure that browser opened by webdriver is always in focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649637/make-sure-that-browser-opened-by-webdriver-is-always-in-focus)

None of the questions i have seen seem to work for me.

I'm using python 3.5 and the latest selenium. The window opens and executes anything I tell however it's in the background and never focuses. Is there something I'm missing?

I have tried iterating over the windows and focusing each one but none of this works.

I would really like this to happen as watching the browser as the script executes is the reason why i'm using this tool.

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: There is no native support for tabs or new window, I suggest you spawn a new browser if you have to.

Comment: @taesu How do I focus that browser in my OS? at a system level is that possible? Or should I use another tool like pyautogui to switch to the window...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot control visibility of content of each opened tab/window automatically. However, you can handle last opened tab/window as below and see what exactly happens on current tab/window:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
google_window = driver.current_window_handle # Define main window
print(driver.title) # Title now is "Google". It is currently visible

driver.execute_script("window.open('http://www.bing.com');") # Open Bing window
bing_window = [window for window in driver.window_handles if window != google_window][0] # Define Bing window
driver.switch_to_window(bing_window)
print(driver.title) # Title now is "Bing". It is currently visible
driver.execute_script("window.close();") # Close Bing window

driver.switch_to_window(google_window)
print(driver.title) # Now title is again "Google". It is currently visible
```

Also you can use `driver.get(URL)` to open new page in current window and navigate in history with `driver.back()` and `driver.forward()`

Comment: To achieve what I am trying to do would you recommend using a window manager tool?

Comment: I don't use window managers, so I cannot recommend you something like that

Comment: I will mark as correct since the first sentence answers my question.