# target __blank doesn't change page source and current url in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I use Selenium with Python to extract some data from a website.
My question is simple, I click on a link which opens with `target="__blank"`, and the problem is that I want to get the current URL of the just opened page. Unfortunately, neither the page URL is changed, nor the page source. I found that changing the element attribute to `target="__self"` does the trick. However, I don't see this trick quite often when I searched around the Internet and that leads me to the question is that the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually another approach is used.
After opening a link in a new tab you can get the list of all tabs:

```
tabs = driver.window_handles
```

And then you can use this list to navigate between the tabs. If you want to go to the second tab you need this code:

```
driver.switch_to.window(tabs[1])
```

If you want to return to the first tab you can use this:

```
driver.switch_to.window(tabs[0])
```

Also after opening a link in a new tab you can switch to the new window using the official example:

```
original_tab = driver.current_window_handle
for tab in driver.window_handles:
        if tab != original_tab:
            driver.switch_to.window(tab)
            break
```

But I myself use the approach I wrote first (the one with `tabs[1]` ).

Answer (score 1):

```
target="_blank"
```

Opens the requested URL in a new Tab/Window.
Seleniums only focusses on the current window, so the newly opened window won't be focussed by Selenium.
Thats why

```
target="_self"
```

works as intended, as it changes the current window.

See target behaviour here: https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/HTML/Attribute/target

Comment: So, is this the best practice or there is a way to focus the just opened window?

Comment: If you want to switch the window, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379560/get-focus-on-the-new-window-in-selenium-webdriver-and-python
I personally would'n recommend this, as opening the URL in the current tab is more predictable.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. Anyway, I found this article which was easier for me to understand: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/ and answered my question, which when I look closely on your answer it looks the same.